# HTML/CSS - Space to right of div

Tags: html, css

Simple question, but for the life of me I cant figure it out. There is space to the right of the image which is a link inside a div how do I get rid of the space to the left of the image?

Code:

```
<style>
div.home a {
float: left;
display: inline;
}
div.home p {
top: 5%;
right: 50%;
}
div.home {
top: 10%
position: absolute;
width: 1400px;

bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: 0;
}

div.home #h1 {
width:  700px;
height: 400px;
display: inline;
background-image: url('parallax.png');
background-size: 700px 400px;
}
div.home #h2 {
width:  700px;
height: 400px;
display: inline;
background-image: url('normal.png');
background-size: 700px 400px;
}
```

```
<div class="home">
<p>Which version would you like?</p>
<a href='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10329732/portfolio/parallasx/index.html' id="h1"></a>
<a href='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10329732/portfolio/index.html' id="h2"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't understand your problem.

Comment: Please post a screenshot and / or a working demo.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because you set #h1 and #h2 an **inline display**. So there's some white space, I guess.

Try adding `white-space:nowrap;` to those elements. Or simply let them as block element (default behavior).